# Java: Use the same code with two different versions of a dependent class

Tags: java

Consider a Java class *Foo* that uses a library *Bar*. *Foo* should be distributed as a binary .class file and use the version of *Bar* that is already existing on a clients classpath.

There are two different versions of *Bar* that only differ in its method signatures. *Foo* should be compatible with both of them.

Example code:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Bar.librarycall("hello from foo");
        //or
        Bar.librarycall("hello from foo",1);
    }
}
//v1
public class Bar {
    public static void librarycall(String argument){
        System.out.println("Bar1: " + argument);
    }
}
//v2
public class Bar {
    public static void librarycall(String argument,int i){
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.println("Bar2: " + argument);
    }
}
```

I want to avoid reflection if possible. How would you propose to create a class *Foo* that is compatible with both versions of *Bar*?

[Edit]

This problem originates in a project I am working on. *Bar* corresponds to an external library I am using but cannot be modified for the code to work (I don't have the source code and the license doesn't allow modifications).

Comment: You would need Bar to extend Bar then have Foo use the child Bar. Or have both Bar's implement BarImpl interface that exposes the methods - however both would then need to have the same method signatures.

Comment: Why not distribute two versions of Foo.class, and let the client use the one that is compatible with their version of Bar? Just like you choose a linux or windows version of a software based on what your OS is. Otherwise, without using reflection, I don't see how it could be possible.

Comment: @JBNizet Foo is part of a Java-based plugin that can be installed using an automatic plugin installer I cannot modify either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A refelective solution.

```
    Class<?> c;
    try {
        c = Class.forName("Bar");
        Method meths[] = c.getMethods();
        Method v1method = null;
        Method v2method = null;
        for(Method m:meths) {
            if(!m.getName().equals("librarycall")) continue;
            if(!Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers())) {
                System.out.println("Should be static");
                continue;
            }
            Class<?> params[] = m.getParameterTypes();
            if(params.length == 1 && params[0].equals(String.class) )
                v1method = m;
            if(params.length == 2 && params[0].equals(String.class) && params[1].equals(Integer.TYPE) )
                v2method = m;
        }
        if(v2method!=null) {
            v2method.invoke(null,"V2",5);
        }
        else if(v1method!=null) {
            v1method.invoke(null,"V1");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("No method found");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

You could use `c = Bar.class;` or if you already have an instance bar of Bar `c = bar.getClass()`. The invoke syntax is for static methods if its non static you need `v1method.invoke(bar,"V1");`.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection does seem like the simplest way. The alternative would be to try calling the second version and catch a `NoSuchMethodException`.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Bar.librarycall("hello from foo",1);
        catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Bar.librarycall("hello from foo");
        }
}
```

This is ugly, and slower, use Reflection its what its there for.

Comment: I don't see how you could compile the above code. You'll have to have either Bar v1 or Bar v2 in the classpath, and one of the two calls will thus not compile.Unless you create your own Bar class containing both methods only for compilation.

Comment: @JB Nizet Good point. Depends a bit on the library v2 might still have a deprecated version of the first method call.

Comment: @JBNizet I could create a dummy version of Foo that contains both methods, v1 and v2. I tried this, but the `NoSuchMethodException` is not caught by the catch statement (and cannot be compiled: `NoSuchMethodException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement`)

Comment: You'll have to trick the compiler into thinking that such an exception can be thrown: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/9720792. But I would use reflection instead of those dirty tricks. BTW, I think you'll have to deal with NoSuchMethodError, not with NoSuchMethodException if you use this dirty trick and not reflection.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this one task that is handled by the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that:

1. You cannot change any of the versions of the Bar class files
2. You have the ability to write new Foo files
3. For some reason, you really want to avoid using Reflection
4. The two Bar files have the same package name

You may need to distribute two versions of the Foo class, as mentioned by JB Nizet in the comment to your question.